# Filter the database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I need to filter the `sql` database based on the user's input for 4 columns in an `asp.net` web Application. This situation, they can select or not all four columns or one column or 2 or etc. All  I have is 2^4(16) possibilities. Whats the best method to filter?

My `gui` screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Please guide me.

I wrote a query for selection of one of four:

```
SELECT acct_number AS AccountNo,
    cust_lname AS Name 
FROM List 
WHERE (ordr_date='" + orderdate + "' 
    OR reader_code='" + rdrCode + "' 
    OR dly_pack_no='" + dlyPack + "' 
    OR walk_seq='" + wlkSeq + "')
```

Comment: can you please show your current query ?

Comment: Yieks! Please use parametrized queries as this is prone to SQL injection.

Comment: Parameterise that query!!

Comment: please take a look at  (Case When Then End) method if you are using sql server

Comment: The best way is to build command and parameters list in your app according to user input. `OR` tricks tend to have bad execution time. And yes, use parameters.

Comment: refer here   http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1213442-338-1.aspx

Comment: @Serg yes this lead to sql injection, avoid by using parameters

Comment: @ARUN, I mean C# code is the right place to build proper parametrized command text (1..4 parameters) and its parameters list. Just 4 `if`s and you get the Sql which runs as fast as it can be. No need for 'universal' Sql command and tricks on server side.

Comment: @Serg But if there is more than five or six join the query, leads to performance issues, stored procedure is better i think , with right parameters passed to it, run better

Comment: @ARUN, currently I see no joins at all in OP's query and no point for procedure which definetly can be the best way in some other case.

Comment: @ARUN Stored procedures don't magically make queries ordered of magnitudes faster.  They can save some compile time since they're pre-compiled (usually) but the main benefit is encapsulating ugly queries from a caller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT acct_number AS AccountNo,
       cust_lname AS Name
FROM List
WHERE (ISNULL(orderdate,'')='' OR ISNULL(ordr_date,'')='' OR ordr_date='" + orderdate + "')
  AND (ISNULL(rdrCode,'')='' OR ISNULL(reader_code,'')='' OR reader_code='" + rdrCode + "')
  AND (ISNULL(dlyPack,'')='' OR ISNULL(dly_pack_no,'')='' OR dly_pack_no='" + dlyPack + "')
  AND (ISNULL(wlkSeq,'')='' OR ISNULL(walk_seq,'')='' OR walk_seq='" + wlkSeq + "')
```

Comment: Thx, it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

try below query.

```
SELECT  acct_number AS AccountNo ,
    cust_lname AS Name
FROM    List
WHERE   ( ordr_date = '" + orderdate + "'
      OR " + orderdate + " = " + orderdate + "
    )
    AND ( reader_code = '" + rdrCode + "'
          OR " + rdrCode + " = " + rdrCode + "
        )
    AND ( dly_pack_no = '" + dlyPack + "'
          OR " + dlyPack + " = " + dlyPack + "
        )
    AND ( walk_seq = '" + wlkSeq + "'
          OR " + wlkSeq + " = " + wlkSeq + "
        )
```

Comment: No.. It doesn't sort. Always giving the same result.

Comment: try to use Moumit answer given below to my answer. which is more appropriate answer then mine.

Answer (score 0):

Build your `WHERE`-clause dynamically and use parameters.

```
SqlCommand select =  new SqlCommand(@"SELECT acct_number AS AccountNo,
    cust_lname AS Name 
    FROM List ");

if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(orderDate)) // use appropriate logic according to data type. I'm assuming string atm.
select.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@ordr_date", Value = orderDate, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar });

 // Repeat for each parameter and then...

 for(int i = 0; i < select.Parameters.Count; i++)
 {
     if(i == 0)
         select.CommandText += " WHERE ";
     else
         // OR as in the filter is not exclusive... depends on the filter logic you want to construct of course. 
         // AND if it has to fulfill all properties
         select.CommandText += " OR ";
     select.CommandText += string.Format("{0} = {0}", select.Parameters[i].Name).Substring(1);
 }
```

Comment: Why `OR` ?  And  why '{1}' ?

Comment: Thx, `{0}` twice of course... `OR` as in the filter is not exclusive... depends on the filter logic you want to construct of course. `AND` if it has to fulfill all properties...